# How can VM options values be used among the resource bundle values?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

In the VM args level, imagine that `-Dparam=value1` is existed, so these vm or enviroment params are wanted to be use in the **message_{lang}.properties** like following.

> message_en.properties

```
text.application.name = ${param}
```

**Is there any notation to use it like that? like injecting value to message resouces from external sources**